# Sonar 'Source files should not have any duplicated blocks' rule doesn't distinguish different literals

Tags: java, sonarqube, code-duplication

I have a simple two-level hierarchy made up of an abstract superclass named AbstractTable,
and three specific subclasses, Table1, Table2 and Table3.

Each subclass provide one different implementation for three absract methods.
For example, Table1 class says:

```java
  @Override
  protected String getSequence() {
    return "seq_table1";
  }
  @Override
  protected String getIdColumn() {
    return "id_table1";
  }
  @Override
  protected String getTable() {
    return "table1";
  }
```

Table2 and Table3 have similar implementations, they response different literals.
However, Sonar does not seem to distinguish the different literals and he tells me that all the lines are duplicated.
**Rule: Source files should not have any duplicated blocks.**

Why? I think sonar should consider different literals as different lines.

**Is the current operation of the rule correct?**
**Can anyone explain to me how to pass the rule in these situations?**

Thanks for advance.

Comment: This is a silly rule and you should consider ignoring it in this instance. Two tokens do not a "block" make.

Answer (score 1):

The answer in https://github.com/SonarSource/SonarJS/issues/717 is for SonarJS but I guess it also holds true for SonarJava.

As for a way to avoid it: You could perhaps override the constructor for the child classes hand have something like this:

```
public class Table {
    private String sequence;
    private String idColumn;
    private String table;

    public Table(String sequence, String idColumn, String table) {
        this.sequence = sequence;
        this.idColumn = idColumn;
        this.table = table;
    }

    //getters and setters if needed
}

public class Table1 {
    
    public Table1() {
        super("seq_table1", "id_table1", "table1");
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi! yes, I had seen that issue but the final tip was to mark the code to ignore the rule and I wasn't satisfied with that. I think Sonar prefers to be preventive in these cases.
Anyway, I will make the refactor that you suggest and closed case. Thanks!